# Explain why the interval $|y-1|<B$ cannot contain y=0 only when $0<B<1$

Tags: interval-arithmetic

Explain why the interval $|y-1|<B$ cannot contain $y=0$ only when $0<B<1$.

I'm not sure where $0<B<1$ comes from

Comment: It doesn't "come from" anywhere. It's the _hypothesis_ for what you are asked to prove. Try by contradiction: what if $B$ is not in that interval? PS You've asked other questions here that have been answered. You should accept answers that help you (the check box) and upvote them too (the up arrow).

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite true.

If $B \le 0$, the "interval" is empty, so we wouldn't call it an interval.

If $B > 1$. the interval does contain $0$, because $|0-1| = 1$.

But the interval doesn't contain $0$ when $B=1$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand where this is coming from now. But how would we know what values of B to look at if we were NOT given the interval $0<B<1$?

Answer (score 1):

With $0\leq|y-1|<B$ we know $0<B$ and when $|y-1|<B$ then
$$1-B<y<1+B$$
but this can't contain $y=0$ so $0<1-B<y$ which concludes $\color{blue}{0<B<1}$.